# Jquery function - on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery code, working 100%.
This is executing on every page load, when i import my js file in the html.
My question, how can i make use of this code, only when the element is present, or call it directly from the element itself? I have similiar functions, but, on html's that dont have specific elements, javascript execution halts. Sometimes because the html elements dont exist on that specific html file.

```
/**
* Message Box Display
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Message-Box" ).slideDown("slow", function() {
    $("#Message-Box").addClass('Show');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#Message-Box').addClass('Hide');
    }, 5000);
});
});
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem. jQuery will not throw an error when no elements on the page matches the selector. When you say "JS execution halts", can you clarify what has exactly happened? Do you get any error messages in your browser console?

Comment: if($("#Message-Box").length > 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var msgbx = $("#Message-Box");
    if (msgbx.length) {
        msgbx.slideDown("slow", function() {
            msgbx.addClass('Show');
            setTimeout(function() {
                msgbx.addClass('Hide');
            }, 5000);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function halting my script was this one:

```
/**
 * Background-Audio
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
   var audioTrack = document.getElementById("Background-Audio");
   if(audioTrack)
   {
    audioTrack.volume = 0.05;
    audioTrack.play();
   }
});
```

Comment: My fix, was adding the if. Error was something of cannot change volume attribute on a null element. That was happening on all the pages that dont have the audio html tag. Thats why the others jquery etc, were not running on them.